# Number of orthogonal list produced by the Gram-Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal

I'm learning about the Gram-Schmidt process, and there's this question:

[image]

Are those list just the list $(e_1,...,e_m)$ produced by the Gram-Schmidt process, with the signs flipped? And if it's true, how do I know that there are not more?

By the way here's the formulation of the process in the textbook:

[image]

Comment: What book is this from? That exercise is simply nonsense! In fact typically there are _infinitely many_ such orthonormal lists, not just $2^m$.

Comment: How do you get infinitely many? Clearly $e_1=\pm \frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|}$. Now $v_1$ and $v_2$ span a two-dimensional space $V_2$, and the orthogonal complement of the span of $v_1$ in $V_2$ is one-dimensional. So you only have two choices for $e_2$. And so on?

Comment: Yes. As an example you can take $V=\mathbb R^3$, $v_1=(1,0,0)$ and $v_2=(1,1,0)$. Then, $e_1=(1,0,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and any rotation around the $z$-axis of these two vectors span the same subspace, showing that there are **uncountable** "'lists".

Comment: @Kusma Once you get your frame you camnrotate it, getting another orthonormal basis.

Comment: I misread the question. There are infinitely many lists such that $(e_1,\dots,e_m)$ has the same span as $(v_1,\dots, v_m)$. But the exercise requires more than that, namely that the span of the first $j$ $e_k$ is the same as the span of the first $j$ $v_k$ for every $j$. Sorry.

Comment: Oh yes. I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right: the $2^m$ possibilities are exactly those given by $(\pm e_1,\pm e_2,\dots, \pm e_m)$ where the $e_j$ are results of Gram-Schmidt.

Let us write $V_j=\operatorname{span}(v_1,\dots,v_j)$. Then $V_1$ is one-dimensional and there are the two unit vectors $\pm \frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|}$ in it. These are your two choices for $e_1$. No other unit vectors span $V_1$. The orthogonal complement $W_2$ of $V_1$ in $V_2$ is also one-dimensional. It is spanned by $v_2-\left<e_1,v_2\right>e_1$, and there are exactly two unit vectors in $W_2$, which are your choices for $e_2$. You can proceed inductively.

The statement is essentially the (almost) uniqueness of orthonormal bases for complete [flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra)), and mentioned in their Wikipedia article.